# Как добавить свою собственную переменную при логине через facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

На моем сайте пользователи логинятся через фейсбук. Необходимо передать в  скрипт redirect_uri, в моем случае это http://domen.ru/fsb_auth.php свою собственную переменную, в моем случае это fgpr - хэш отпечатка браузера пользователя. Я делаю так:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=139353283100583&redirect_uri=http://domen.ru/fsb_auth.php&response_type=code&scope=public_profile,email,user_friends&fgpr=f568f4a2997fb1c62f70caecc4efc782

Но к сожалению fgpr не передается в redirect_uri, там присутствует только $_GET['code']. Может кто-то знает как передать свою переменную в redirect_uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `Facebook oAuth` ваш fgpr - неизвестный параметр, и конечно вам обратно ничего не будет приходить.. если хотите передать/получить данные при запросе, вам просто надо передать значение через `&state=...` вот тогда и api вам с ответом вернёт ваши данные )
например:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&state=YOUR_DATA
```